# How do I get two instances of a class in Python that I can edit individually?

Tags: python, copy

I know this is probably a repeat but beats me if I can find the answer on here.  I want to be able to have different instances of a class that can hold different values. I've tried deep and shallow copies, I've tried copying the class proper, instances of the class, you name it.

```
>>> class classy:
...   a = 1
...   b = 2
... 
>>> import copy
>>> x = copy.deepcopy(classy)
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(classy)
>>> x.a = 100
>>> y.a
100
```

So essentially I want y.a to return 1 instead of 100.

Thanks

Comment: You should read the python docs on classes: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `instance variables`. That's what they're for.

```
class classy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

x = classy()
y = classy()
x.a = 100
>>> print y.a
1
```

Comment: Note that even his initial code will work, if he uses instances instead of classes.  But this is still the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jayanth has shown the way to do it.  I just want to point out the key problem with your code.

Your question title asks about instances, but your code has no instances.  You have only a class.  If you want instances of a class, you need to make instances, which is done by *calling* the class:

```
>>> class classy:
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
>>> x = classy()
>>> y = classy()
>>> x.a = 100
>>> y.a
1
```

Note that Jayanth does this in his answer as well.  The reason why the above code works, even without using instance attributes as shown in Jayanth's answer, is somewhat more complex, but the basic point is vital: instances and classes are two different things.  You make instances from classes by calling the class.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with classes and instances in Python.